# React Native - how to handle zoom in/out event using mapbox gl

Tags: reactjs, react-native, maps, mapbox-gl

I am using mapbox-gl library, and I want to show marker for zoomed area..
How to handle zoom in / out event as no method provided in below docs

[https://github.com/react-native-mapbox-gl/maps/blob/master/docs/MapView.md]

https://github.com/react-native-mapbox-gl/maps/blob/master/docs/MapView.md

Comment: You could use `onRegionDidChange` then run [`map.getZoom()`](https://github.com/react-native-mapbox-gl/maps/blob/1aa5b6189d95466ae12754ce1706b60e21e26f93/docs/MapView.md#getzoom) and compare with previous zoom state.